# Can't link GLFW C++; Added the .dll, .h, .lib, but still getting LNK2019

Tags: c++, opengl, properties, glfw, lnk2019

I've added the .dll to Windows/System32, the .lib to VS/lib, and the .h to the VS/include.

All that would be left is linking it through the project. This is what I have:

---

```
#include <glfw.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    if (!glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 8, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
        return -1;

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
    {
        /* Render here */

        /* Swap front and back buffers and process events */
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSwapBuffers referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwGetWindowParam referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwOpenWindow referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Danny\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OGL2\Debug\OGL2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

---

I've went to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker >
Added the following to Additional Dependencies:

---

```
opengl32.lib;GLFW.lib;glu32.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

---

And for good measure, I also set Ignore All Default Libraries to "No".

I know I should have linked: `opengl32.lib, GLFW.lib, glu32.lib, kernel32.lib and user32.lib`

Unfortunately, the LNK 2019 problems persist. Really am unsure why. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

<strike>The external names indicate that your project is building for a 64-bit target (32-bit DLL exports generally have the `@nn` suffix used by the stdcall calling convention).  I'll bet your libraries are build for a 32-bit target.</strike>

Change the project settings to Win32 instead of x64.

I guessed incorrectly - the unresolved external symbols such as `_glfwSwapBuffers` indicate that you're building for a 32-bit target.  When building for a 64-bit target, the external names do not get decorated with an underscore.

But the basic solution is the same - make sure that the target that is being built is the same as the target that the libraries you have are.  So if you've downloaded the 64-bit GLFW libraries, make sure your VS project is building for a Win64 target.

I was able to compile and link your test program after extracting the 64-bit GLFW binary distribution into `c:\temp`:

```
C:\temp>cl /I c:\temp\glfw-2.7.7.bin.WIN64\include\GL test.cpp c:\temp\glfw-2.7.7.bin.WIN64\lib-msvc110\GLFWDLL.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
c:\temp\glfw-2.7.7.bin.WIN64\lib-msvc110\GLFWDLL.lib

C:\temp>
```

Comment: Or install the 32 bit version of GLEW. Also take note that the OpenGL library is always called opengl32.dll/lib regardless of the target architecture.

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit version of GLFW because I thought it'd be best to download the same bit-architecture as my computer. Should I get the 32 bit one? I attempted to change project settings to Win32 because That does seem the most logical, but alas, the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error message . I notice there is no .lib file in my glfw folder ,Because I download  source package, You need download pre-compile binaries version,
Then I got it to work;[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's blatantly obvious now that I didn't have precompiled binaries in my folder, but I just didn't think about it before.